# Incompatible peer dependency to @angular/core: Angular update

Tags: angular, angular7, npm-install, ng-upgrade, npm-update

I am trying to upgrade my angular application from version 6 to version 7. I am using below command to do so, but its throwing a warning. I don't want to use "force" commands as it may cause further consequences. Please find the details below

**Command used**

```
npx @angular/cli@7 update @angular/cli@7 @angular/core@7
```

**Warning message**

Kindly help me to resolve this. Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you upgrading from angular 6 to 7? The latest version is 13 (!). In any case, maybe you are updating in incremental steps. If so, you will probably get a lot of those messages.
This warning basically tells you that the dependency `ng2-go-top-buttom` is incompatible with angular 7. Looking at the [package.json](https://github.com/annapogorelova/ng2-go-top-button/blob/master/package.json) file from the package:

```
"@angular/core": ">=8.0.0 <9.0.0",
```

Which means it is only compatible with Angular 8.
This seems like an abandoned project, If I were you, I'd remove it alltogether.

Comment: Initially this project was made in Angular 5 and it was working fine. Late it was migrated to version 6 and now we are upgrading it to version 7

Comment: It is how it is, maybe a prior version of the lib was fine with angular 5.

Comment: yes But if I am upgrading it to higher version I think their should be provision for this lib as well.